# Initial state for my rtk slice is not being saved in store as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Currently learning how to use RTK with typescript. I have 2 slices, one that I've made with RTK query to fetch data (called `apiSlice.ts`), and another that uses createSlice to handle synchronous state change for my todo app (called `snackbarSlice.ts`).

The initial state I've set in the snackbarSlice are not being saved to the store at all, checked in the chrome redux devtools and also console.logged as well, but they do contain the apiSlice related info, just note the snackbar related info. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? I feel like I've been starting at this for way too long.

In the console, I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isOpen') on CustomSnackbar (CustomSnackbar.tsx:12:1) which makes sense given the state object doesn't have an isOpen key.

Below is my code:

`snackbarSlice.ts`:

```
import { RootState } from "../store";

type SnackbarState = {
  content: string;
  isOpen: boolean;
};

const initialState: SnackbarState = {
  content: "",
  isOpen: false,
};

export const snackbarSlice = createSlice({
  name: "snackbar",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    openSnackbar: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.isOpen = true;
      state.content = action.payload;
    },
    closeSnackbar: (state) => {
      state.isOpen = false;
      state.content = "";
    },
  },
});

export const { openSnackbar, closeSnackbar } = snackbarSlice.actions;

export const selectIsSnackbarOpen = (state: RootState): boolean =>
  state.snackbar.isOpen;

export const selectSnackbarContent = (state: RootState): string =>
  state.snackbar.content;

export default snackbarSlice.reducer;
```

rootReducer.ts

```
import { apiSlice } from "./features/apiSlice";
import snackbarReducer from "./features/snackbarSlice";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  snackbar: snackbarReducer,
  [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store.ts

```
import { apiSlice } from "./features/apiSlice";
import rootReducer from "./rootReducer";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});

export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

index.tsx

```
import { App } from "./components/app/App";
import React from "react";
import { ApiProvider } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { apiSlice } from "./store/features/apiSlice";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store/store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ApiProvider api={apiSlice}>
        <App />
      </ApiProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

customSnackbar.tsx

```
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../hooks/reduxHooks";
import {
  closeSnackbar,
  selectIsSnackbarOpen,
  selectSnackbarContent,
} from "../../store/features/snackbarSlice";
import styles from "./CustomSnackbar.module.css";

export const CustomSnackbar = (): ReactElement => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const isSnackbarOpen = useAppSelector(selectIsSnackbarOpen);
  const snackbarContent = useAppSelector(selectSnackbarContent);

  const handleClose = (): void => {
    dispatch(closeSnackbar());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isSnackbarOpen && (
        <div className={styles["snackbar"]}>
          <div>
            <span className={styles["snackbar-btn"]} onClick={handleClose}>
              x
            </span>
            {snackbarContent}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and in any file where I need to open the snackbar, I run the following code: `ispatch(openSnackbar("An error occurred while deleting task."));`

Any thoughts on what I could be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be `ApiProvider` in `index.tsx`. That is extraneous and unnecessary since the `apiSlice` should already be included in the store when it's passed to `Provider`.

[ApiProvider](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/ApiProvider)

> Can be used as a Provider if you **do not already have a Redux
> store**.

> ### DANGER
>
> Using this together with an existing Redux store will cause them to
> conflict with each other. If you are already using Redux, please
> follow the instructions as shown in the Getting Started guide.

The app is using the closest Redux context/Provider, which is the `ApiProvider` and it doesn't include the `snackbar` state/reducer.

Remove the `ApiProvider` component.

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Done, it works! Thank you so much Drew! And that makes sense. Should ApiProvider only be used when you aren't using a Provider, then? What is it's purpose?

Comment: @star98 That's the first quote, it *can* be used as a Redux Provider if your app isn't already using a Redux store. Your app is clearly already using a Redux store. I guess you could think of it as "Redux-lite" ‍♂️ if you just need the query bits and not the global state management stuff. I actually needed to look up in the docs what `ApiProvider` was. Seems it serves an edge-case since most apps looking to use RTKQ are already using RTK, a.k.a. Redux.

Comment: The purpose is to have RTK features in the codebase without Redux, which isn't ready for the Redux boilerplate yet.